# Looking for a way to convert this nested dictionary into a pandas data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I'm trying to convert a file with output like d1 below into a simple table with python. I've tried quite a few methods but I can't seem to get it done.

d1 = {'results': [{'created_at': '2021-01-08', 'id': '644d', 'list_id': '73e8'},{'created_at': '2021-01-09', 'id': '645d', 'list_id': '73e10'}]}

Solutions from these posts have not worked for me:
[How can I fill a dataframe from a recursive dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534751/how-can-i-fill-a-dataframe-from-a-recursive-dictionary-values)
[Construct pandas DataFrame from items in nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary)
[How can I fill a dataframe from a recursive dictionary values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65534751/how-can-i-fill-a-dataframe-from-a-recursive-dictionary-values)

I've tried the pd.DataFrame.from_dict method in a few recursive ways but to no avail. Any help out there would be much appreciated!

p.s. The output would be this:

| created_at | id | list_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-08 | 644d | 73e8 |
| 2021-01-09 | 645d | 73e10 |

Comment: hi might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(d1['results'])`?

Comment: Thanks @MYousefi! That was much easier than I made it out to be.